# Why doesn't link to a specific section id of navlink using react router dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to link a section ID using NavLink of react-router-dom but the link is requested to the server but does not link the specific id.
I want to link section Id with Navlink so that I can easily call the Id by clicking on the Navlink.

```
*Navbar.js*

import React from "react";
import "./Navbar.css";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <nav>
                <div className='container spaceB flex'>
                    <div className='leftSide'>
                        <NavLink className='navLink' to={"/"}>
                            <h1 className='logoH'>{"<Rajib/>"}</h1>
                        </NavLink>
                    </div>
                    <div className='rightSide'>
                        <ul className='flex'>
                            <NavLink className='navLink' to='/#intro'>
                                <li>About</li>
                            </NavLink>
                            <NavLink className='navLink' to='/#skills'>
                                <li>Skills</li>
                            </NavLink>
                            <NavLink to='/#works' className='navLink'>
                                <li>Works</li>
                            </NavLink>
                        </ul>
                        <NavLink className='navLink' to='/#contact'>
                            <button className='btn'>Contact</button>
                        </NavLink>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
};

export default Navbar;

*App.js*

import "./App.css";
import Intro from "./components/common/Intro";
import Navbar from "./components/common/Navbar";
import Services from "./components/common/Skills";
import Works from "./components/common/Works";
import Contact from "./components/common/Contact";
function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <header>
                <Navbar />
            </header>
            <main>
                <Intro />
                <Services />
                <Works />
                <Contact />
            </main>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;

*index.js*

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/' exact element={<App />} />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Please suggest the best solution so that i can link the section by calling it's Id in NavLink when clicking the specific navmenu.

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you using? If using v5 then you can use [react-router-hash-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) to link to specific anchor IDs. If you are using v6 there is no current working solution I'm aware of. There is a current [issue](https://github.com/rafgraph/react-router-hash-link/issues/92) filed though, if you want to track.

Comment: react-router-dom   -version: v6

Comment: Now it's working by using react-router-hash-link 
Thanks @DrewReese